# Error while trying to run nodemon server from a Docker container: sh: 1: nodemon: not found

Tags: docker

I have Windows 7 on my machine and installed Docker.
When I'm trying to run nodemon server from the container I created, I got this error:

```
> nodemon ./server.js

sh: 1: nodemon: not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! node@1.0.0 start: `nodemon ./server.js`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-10-05T14_36_10_858Z-debug.log
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:12.18

WORKDIR C:\Users\Lior\Desktop\Web development course - Part 2\smart-brain-api

COPY ./ ./

RUN npm install
 
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "node",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "script.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "clarifai": "^2.9.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "knex": "^0.21.6",
    "pg": "^8.3.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4"
  },
  "description": ""
}
```

**NOTE:** when I run the nodemon server outside the container, it works well.

Any help please?
Thanks

Comment: If `nodemon` works for you outside of Docker, why not just use that?  What are you hoping to gain by using Docker here?  How are you starting the container (do you use Docker volumes to overwrite the image content)?

Comment: I'm using the container as a part of course I took to learn how to run apps on Docker and I don't know what do you mean by Docker volumes.
I'm Building The Docker Image That way:
`docker build -t superawsomecontainer `
And I run it that way:
`docker run -it  superawsomecontainer`